# How to create cache asynchronously to reduce loadtime of app/page?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

At the moment I have a CacheHelper. It creates cache for datasets to reduce loadtime. In the global.asax (right place?) I have the creation of the cache. The loadtime increases with 12 seconds when executing the creation of the cache. So now I would like to create the cache asynchronous.

[EDIT wrong example code]

```
public static void Create()
{
    var cachekey = "api_TaskSchedulerApiV2Controller_Get";
    var allItems = SchedulerTaskHelper.GetAllTasks();
    cache.Add(cachekey, allItems, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)));
}
```

```
public static List<TaskSchedulerGridViewModel> GetCachedItems()
{
    return (List<TaskSchedulerGridViewModel>)cache.Get("api_TaskSchedulerApiV2Controller_Get");
}
```

The issue I think I will run into is that the dataset is retrieved while the cache is not yet created. Any ideas how to solve this issue? Thanks :-)

Comment: But isn't it executed synchronically when using ```await```? (I made an edit to my post)

Comment: _"But isn't it executed synchronically when using await?"_ - no.  Are you thinking of `.Result()`?

Comment: @MickyD I understand what you say. It was not meant like that. My question is how I can use the ObjectCache class asynchrone.

Comment: No problem.  Have edited your question a bit.

Comment: One thing to consider and it depends on whether you can edit the underlying cache system or not, is whether you want to load _all_ items into the cache at start or simply load an item _during first time it is requested (deferred)_.  The former takes longer and could block any read requests.  The latter won't block as much and may be more efficient if a measurable number of items are not needed right away since the cache is gradually built up over time as needed.